# Column A is LIKE column B MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a way to filter rows where column A is like column B. In the query below I want the first row to be returned. I have not used much SQL lately, so I am a bit rusty, but this simple task has been bugging me.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (A VARCHAR (100), B VARCHAR (100))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('Anton', 'AntonBertus'), ('Leo', 'Huub')
```

My wrong attempts:

```
SELECT * FROM #T WHERE A LIKE B
SELECT * FROM #T WHERE A LIKE '%'+B+'%'

DECLARE @B VARCHAR (100)
SET @B = (SELECT B FROM #T)
SELECT * FROM #T WHERE CONTAINS (A, @B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the LIKE Operator as below. This will return the row if any part of B is LIKE A.

```
SELECT * FROM #T
WHERE B LIKE '%'+A+'%'
```

If you wants only starting part to check, use the below script-

```
SELECT * FROM #T
WHERE B LIKE ''+A+'%'
```

Comment: :) hope this will help you @SQL_M

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are using `like`, you want the longer value to be on the left side and the smaller one on the right side of the `like` operator:

```
Where 'Zohar Peled' LIKE 'Zohar%' -- will give a result
Where 'Zohar' LIKE 'Zohar Peled%' -- will not give a result
```

Assuming you don't know which column has the longer value, you can use `or`:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM #T
WHERE A LIKE '%'+ B +'%'
OR B LIKE '%'+ A +'%'
```

This should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: Aside: In many cases the pattern (on the right) may be longer than the searched string (on the left), e.g. `@Zip like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Answer Should be like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM #T 

SELECT
    *
FROM #T t
WHERE B LIKE '%' + t.A + '%'
```

**Output:-**

[image]